# How to use zonal statistics in R with shapefile

Tags: r, zonal-statistics

I have a county shapefile and a DEM raster, I want to extract mean DEM of every counties.
There is a function 'zonal' in raster package, however, it requires raster not shapefile.

[image]
How can I do this in R?

Comment: Have you tried the [exctract() function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/extract) instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As recommended `raster::extract` will accomplish what you are after. However, from a computational speed and modernization standpoint, I would recommend using the terra package, which is a replacement for raster. The `terra::extract` function is almost identical to the raster version but, written in Rcpp and notably faster. Whereas the syntax is the same as `raster::extract`, the terra version requires coercing your polygon vector data to a terra Vect class, which can be done in the function eg., `terra::extract(raster, vect(polys), 'mean')`. The polygons can be an sf or sp class.

Another alternative is `exact_extract` function in the exactextractr package, which allows for a weighted overlay (eg., mean, sum) based on the fractional intersection of cells with the polygons. The polygons need to be an sf class object but the raster(s) can be raster or terra objects. You can read in your polygons using `sf::st_read`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extract` function from the raster package:

```
Description:

     Extract values from a Raster* object at the locations of spatial
     vector data. There are methods for points, lines, and polygons
     (classes from `sp` or `sf`), for a matrix or data.frame of points.
     You can also use cell numbers and Extent (rectangle) objects to
     extract values.
```

The first parameter is a raster, the second can be spatial polygons read in from a shapefile using `readOGR` or similar. Read the help for more complete info.